# Can't run script with proz on Ubuntu

Tags: scripts, ios

I am trying to compile iOS code on Ubuntu. Trying to set up all tools according to:

https://code.google.com/p/ios-toolchain-based-on-clang-for-linux/wiki/HowTo_en

I get stuck on the point: `./cctools-ld64.sh`

In line 27 of the script it complains that proz command is unknown.
I tried to install prozilla, but required packages are unavailable for Ubuntu.

Another problem is, that it complains, that the wanted file is unavailable:

```
LD64_URL=http://www.opensource.apple.com/tarballs/ld64/$LD64_FILE
LD64_FILE=ld64-236.3.tar.gz
```

Do you have an idea, or should I forget iOS on Ubuntu?

Comment: Try [Adding ProZilla](http://www.unixmen.com/downloading-made-easy-fast-apt-proz-prozilla/) to get over the first hump, or try [this method](https://code.google.com/p/iphone-dev/wiki/Building)

Answer (score 0):

Open the shell script and replace

```
proz -k=20  --no-curses
```

With

```
wget
```

If you don't have wget you can `sudo apt-get install wget` or use `curl`...